# Button is not showing in Google Nest devices but showing properly in Mobile Assistant

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-assistant

I am using google actions for one of our clients. We are using Button to navigate the user to a specific URL but Button is not showing in the Nest devices, but it is showing fine in Mobile Assistant devices.

Anyway, where we can enable the same?

Also if there is no option, what is the way to identify if the user logged in the device has button functionality enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Buttons that link to a webpage are not available on smart displays. In the platform different devices have certain limitations. As such, the device running the action sends [capabilities](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/reference/rest/Shared.Types/Capability?hl=en) that define what is possible. You will need to check for the `WEB_LINK` capability.

In the [Node.js library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/assistant-conversation-nodejs) this would be done as such:

```js
app.handle('handle-name', conv => {
    const supportsWebLink = conv.device.capabilities.includes('WEB_LINK')
    if (!supportsWebLink) {
        // Behavior for Nest Hub and other devices
    }
})
```

I see you have the `dialogflow-es` tag rather than `actions-builder`, so to do it in Dialogflow:

```js
app.intent('intent-name', conv => {
    const supportsWebLink = conv.device.capabilities.includes('WEB_LINK')
    if (!supportsWebLink) {
        // Behavior for Nest Hub and other devices
    }
})
```